# Riddle: "Tread on the living / They make not a mumble..."

Tags: riddle

A kinda creepy riddle (the answer is not as sinister as it would perhaps appear):

> Tread on the living,
>  They make not a mumble.
>  Tread on the
> dead,
>  They mutter and grumble.
>  What are they?

What's the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Leaves

Tread on the living,
They make not a mumble.

> When green and alive, leaves tend to be soft and won't make make of a sound when you step on them

Tread on the dead,
They mutter and grumble.

> As leaves die, they dry out and produce an audible crunching sound when stepped on.

Comment: This was precisely my first thought too, but I didn't feel that 'mutter and grumble' really described the true sound onomatopoeically enough to fit pleasingly (to me they would shout and swear, in an 'OI, WATCH IT!' kind of way). Not a criticism of the answer of course, but I'd be interested to know what emotions/voice others would ascribe to these :)

Comment: hey! It's poetic license!

Comment: @HexagonalImpossibilities Fair enough! Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it's correct :)

Comment: oh yeah sorry @hexomino, forgot- now ticked!